# select a specific month in calendar react

Tags: reactjs

I am currently using react-multi-date-picker calendar and unable to start from and end to specific month.It is taking current month as default

can some help me with this!

```
const [calanderDate, setCalanderDate] = useState(new DateObject())

<Calendar
    disableMonthPicker
    disableYearPicker
    buttons={false}
    numberOfMonths={15}
    onChange={(e) => setCalanderDate(e)}
    value={calanderDate}
    fullscreen={false}
    multiple
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the useState into [] this way there will be no default data.

```
 export default function App() {
      const [calanderDate, setCalanderDate] = useState([]);
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Calendar
            buttons={false}
            numberOfMonths={1}
            onChange={(array) => {
              //Array of Dateobjecs
              alert("selected dates :\n" + array.join(",\n"));
            }}
            value={calanderDate}
            fullscreen={false}
            multiple={true}
            range={true}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: i tried this but it is taking October only as default